# Xamarin Unified API

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am in the middle of converting our code to use Xamarin.iOS. Many methods have been renamed and their replacement is not always obvious. To make matters worse - most (if not all?) examples are using monotouch.dll

example: ios7 microphone record

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8561/ios7-microphone-record

Specifically this line:

```
recorder = AVAudioRecorder.ToUrl(url, settings,out error);
```

The static method ToUrl() no longer exists. Can someone direct me to examples for this stuff that apply to the unified API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Many methods have been renamed

There will soon be more (and updated) information for the **unified** API and how to migrate from it available. Right now the initial (for the preview) documentation is available from:

- [Unified API](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/);
- [Native Types](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/nativetypes/);
- [32 and 64 bits considerations](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/32-and-64/);
- [Updating iOS applications](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/); and
- [Updating Bindings for Unified](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/update_binding_unified/)

Link to those documents should be future proof (content will be updated with new releases).

> most (if not all?) examples are using monotouch.dll

You can see [migrated samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/magic-types) from the `magic-types` branch in github. Once finalized the Unified API will be available directly from `master`.

Answer (score 0):

`AVAudioRecorder.ToUrl (NSUrl url, NSDictionary settings, out NSError error);`

has been replaced by

`AVAudioRecorder.Create (NSUrl url, AudioSettings settings, out NSError error);`

The settings parameter looks like it's changed it's type from a NSDictionary to AudioSettings instance. But the AudioSettings class has a constructor that lets you provide a NSDictionary, so it should be an easy change.